# Any benefit to evaluating the same expression twice in an if-statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean-expression

I'm doing some maintenance on foreign (i.e. not mine) C# code and I've come across what amounts to this scenario:

```
class AClass : System.Windows.Forms.Form {
    bool aMemberField = false;

    void someMemberFunction() {
        if ((aMemberField || aMemberField)) return;
        // function continues
    }

    // more members ...
}
```

Is there any benefit/effect to doing this in C#, or is it simply a waste of an evaluation? If it is of any worth, this part of the project is a Windows Form class, as denoted by the class inheritance.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Your answers confirmed what I had already suspected, so thank you. I looked through the project to find the places the member field is used in other expressions, and in nearly all of the expressions in which it's evaluated together with another member, it's the same *other* member, i.e.

```
if((aMemberField || bMemberField))
```

So I'm inclined to think that it's simply a typo by the programmer, and copy-paste has propagated it to one other instance in the program.

Comment: In the extract provided, since `aMemberField == false`, then `if ((aMemberField || aMemberField)) return;` is *redundant* and can be *eliminated*.

Comment: This is a redundant code...you can place the code where it gets pudated dynamically ;)

Comment: No - there is no benefit to this. It's redundant. The only time it might make a difference would be if it was a function call, rather than a variable (i.e. `if (KillOnePerson() || KillOnePerson())` tries to kill 2 people, and the if test passes if at least 1 is killed - if that's the specific behaviour you want, then great).

Comment: Any benefit? Probably not, unless the expression happened to have a side effect, no. But even that would be a stretch. The compiler will probably optimize it away anyway. It's probably a product of an alternate condition that where the differentiating factors were removed and nothing else. I see no point in keeping it.

Comment: You're sure that you haven't simplified some thread double-locking mechanism? On the face of it, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: From the look of it. The extra check does nothing. However if the "aMemberfield" is the some deferred execution then be careful.

Comment: @Carlos Yes I'm sure it's not been simplified, the only thing I've done is replace names. And I'm 99% sure there's no threading involved as the project has gone through the hassle of reinventing the wheel and made their own concurrency model, so it's relatively easy to see where multi-threading is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
if ((aMemberField || aMemberField))
```

is a short-circuiting evaluation. If the variable were true, only one would be evaluated and it would enter the block of code beneath the conditional statement. If the variable were false, it would run a useless and redundant secondary evaluation.

At any rate, here's the `IL` for it.

**if (aMemberField || aMemberField)**

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // aMemberField
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // aMemberField
IL_0004:  ldloc.0     // aMemberField
IL_0005:  or          
IL_0006:  stloc.1     
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     
IL_0008:  brfalse.s   IL_000C
IL_000A:  br.s        IL_000C
IL_000C:  ret
```

**if (aMemberField)**

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // aMemberField
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // aMemberField
IL_0004:  stloc.1     
IL_0005:  ldloc.1     
IL_0006:  brfalse.s   IL_000A
IL_0008:  br.s        IL_000A
IL_000A:  ret
```

It's useless. Even with some very strange edge case (See Siderite's answer), it's just proof that the code needs some serious refactoring.

Comment: I expected as much. And honestly, as it stands right now, we'll be remaking the program from scratch. It's a mess indeed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pattern that needs to evaluate an expression twice, but it's related to multithreaded access. You check if the resource is available, if so you lock it (prevent further modifications), then you check if the resource is available again, since it could have been modified right before you locked it.

The code you presented there is just redundant. Even in multithreaded scenarios, if the first evaluation is true, then the second is not run, if the first is false and the second is true, that's a very random event. Plus the compiler would probably optimize the s**t out of it and it wouldn't work as described above anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It would not make sense to do something like this. I can't think of a situation where it would as it will always return the value of `aMemberField` since `true || true = true` and `false || false = false`.